# Why does the screen display dead pixels at 144 Hz, but not at 60 Hz?

Tags: display, resolution, high-resolution, dead-pixel, stuck-pixel

I'm using [Asus TUF Gaming F15](https://www.asus.com/us/Laptops/For-Gaming/TUF-Gaming/2021-ASUS-TUF-Gaming-F15/) which is working really fine for me, but recently I noticed that at 144 Hz there is a black horizontal stripe (dead pixels) at the bottom of the screen. When I change the settings to 60 Hz it goes away and the screen works normal without any dead pixels. This is my first time using a 144 Hz screen laptop, so I can't say that it is dead pixels, or a setting problem, or a resolution problem.

Recently I did:

1. Update Windows 10
2. Also, Armoury Crate got updated (the SDK was installed with the Windows 10 update)

Any suggestions?

I used [a YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZjdrMuKpaCI) to fix dead pixels, but it isn't working.

Here are [the pictures](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1qTEr-7oOUFlV8zo6Qj7qxAzxBuACfuY-?usp=sharing) of the screen at different frequencies.

#### 60 Hz

[image]

#### 144 Hz

[image]

P.S.: Hitherto, only game I played on this laptop is *[Counter-Strike](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counter-Strike)* 1.6 which runs on 144 Hz. Rest all the time, my PC is working on 60 Hz.

Comment: @Ramhound- not quite, dead pixels can have any color, depending on what has malfunctioned. Green or cyan (green + blue) dead pixels are quite common.

Comment: @Ramhound thanks for the knowledge but what should I do about the problem I am facing?

Comment: @Ramhound I haven't captured screenshot.. it is a snapshot from my mobile

Comment: Is the laptop under warranty ?   This should be your first option, look it up today.  Time's wasting !

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**A contact field issue. Avoid using 144 Hz and plan to replace the display panel.**

What you show are essentially not dead pixels. Dead pixels are individual pixels, not the entire line. What you see is likely a problem in vertical contact field, namely in one or more of contacts which power affected horizontal lines.

Some of these contact failures - like yours - are dependent on working frequencies. At some frequencies, their impedance (electric resistance) is unexpectedly higher than at others. Then there is not enough voltage left for pixels themselves. This explains what you see.

This loosened connection can emerge during the manufacturing process or later by mechanical stress during use. For example, it is frequent in laptops carried in stuffed backpacks, where the stuff is forcing the display chassis to bend.

The greater impedance at a particular contact point leads to increased heat production in that area. In return, this may lead to further damages of the contact point. ⇒ In the future, expect the same damage appearing not only at 144 Hz, but at any frequency of the display panel. And it may spread to neighboring lines of pixels. To mitigate spreading of the problem, avoid further heating of that place, i. e. avoid using the display in frequencies where the missing lines are appearing. Use the display only at frequencies where everything works normally.

On laptops where LCD contact fields are placed close to the surface of the display, you can even feel the heat by touching the problematic area. This witnesses that there is more thermal stress going to that area, leading to more severe damage of the same place in the future. In some cases, gently pressing the damaged place may lead to pixel lines reappearing, even at 144 Hz, but only while the pressure is applied. In such a case, the problem with damaged contacts has mechanical nature - they are mechanically loose. But the heat can contribute to this by affecting the glue  which holds the contacts attached.

To permanently fix this, contact a service center where they will fit an entirely new LCD panel assembly which also includes contact fields.  Typically this can be covered within the warranty of the device.

Comment: Thanks! But I don't carry my laptop. It is always lying on my study table. I don't know how I got it but thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Cicada - it can be a defect from the manufacturing process. If possible, try applying your warranty. It certainly covers cases like this one. Especially if you did not expose the device to any mechanical stress by yourself.

Comment: Thanks!!! Laptop's warranty expired just last month. I have to bare the cost :(

Comment: @Cicada Check consumer protection laws of your country. The warranty may not be your only bet. Additionally, if you have to pay: I'd try finding a cheap screen on e.g. ebay. Have changed cracked screens previously, generally finding panels for 100-150$

Comment: @Cicada Some manufacturers offer a deal to extend the warranty that you can accept for a limited time after expiration. Check it now - in all cases whatever fee they want will be cheaper than a new laptop.